# Finding $\int_0^{\infty}xe^{-\lambda x} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

How to integrate:

$$\int_0^\infty x \, \lambda e^{-\lambda x} \, dx$$

---

I tried using integration by parts:

Let $u = x$ and $dv = \lambda e^{-\lambda x} \, dx$

Then $du = dx$

And $v = - \lambda e ^{-\lambda x}$

Correct so far?

Then

$$\begin{aligned}
uv - \int v \, du &= -\lambda x e^{-\lambda x} - \int (- \lambda e^{- \lambda x}) dx \\
&= -\lambda x e^{-\lambda x} - \lambda e^{-\lambda x}
\end{aligned}$$

---

The correct answer from lecture notes

[image]

---

**UPDATE 2**

Let $u=\lambda x$ and $dv = e^{-\lambda x} dx$

Then $du = \lambda \, dx$

$$dv = e^{-\lambda x} \, dx$$

Let $y = -\lambda x$

Then $dy = -\lambda \, dx$

So $dx = -\frac{1}{\lambda} dy$

$$\begin{aligned}
v &= \int e^u \cdot - \frac{1}{\lambda} du \\
&= - \frac{1}{\lambda} e^{-\lambda x}
\end{aligned}$$

But here I seem to have an extra $- \frac{1}{\lambda}$ in $v$?

If I continue using integration by parts, I get:

$$-x e^{-\lambda x} + \color{red}{\frac{1}{\lambda}} \int e^{-\lambda x} \, dx$$

Comment: If $dv = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}$, then $v = -e^{-\lambda x}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer in not just $ -xe^{-\lambda x}  $. Correct answer with limits is $ [-xe^{-\lambda x}]^{\infty} _0$ + ${\int^{\infty}_0e^{-\lambda x}dx}$ which turns out to be $1/\lambda.$

Explanation:Applying integration by parts (the correct way)

$${\int{x\lambda}e^{-\lambda x}dx} = {}\lambda x {\int e^{-\lambda x}dx} - {\lambda}{\int}[{d(x)/dx}. {\int e^{-\lambda x}}]dx$$

Now apply limit and calculate
$$ = [-xe^{-\lambda x}]^{\infty} _0 + {\int^{\infty}_0e^{-\lambda x}dx} $$
$$=1/\lambda$$

Comment: Just noticed that and updated OP, but looks like my answer is still wrong? My answer factors to $(-\lambda e^{-\lambda x})(x-1)$ which I don't think I will get $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ from there?

Comment: Assume ${\lambda x} $ to be the function to be differentiated and $e^{ - \lambda x}$ to be integrated.

Comment: Just tried that, I seem to have made a mistake somewhere? My $v$ seems to have an extra $-1/\lambda$ term? See update 2 in OP.

Comment: if your $v= e^{- \lambda x} $ then your $dv = -{\lambda}e^{- \lambda x} dx$.

Comment: Did u mean $dv$ instead of $v$ and vice versa? We pick $dv$ not $v$ right?

Comment: OK I got it ... $du = \lambda \, dx$ the $\lambda$s cancel

Comment: By the way $[-x e^{-\lambda x}]^\infty_0$ how do I reason it to be 0? Its because $\infty \cdot 0 = 0$ right? $e^{-\lambda \infty} = 0$?

Comment: One way to look at the answer is $ \lim_{x\to \infty} {xe^{- \lambda x}} $. Write ${xe^{- \lambda x}}$ as $\frac{x}{e^{\lambda x}}$ and apply L'Hospital's rule.

Answer (score 1):

How to integrate:

$$\int_0^\infty x \, \lambda e^{-\lambda x} \, dx \Longrightarrow -\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_0^\infty  u\, e^{u} \, \Longrightarrow (-\frac{1}{\lambda})e^u(u + 1) + C \Longrightarrow -\frac{1}{\lambda}(e^{-\lambda x}(\lambda x - 1) + C)$$

1) Choose $u = -\lambda x$. $-du = \lambda dx$. No need for integration by parts so early.

Comment: So the answer is not $- x e^{-\lambda x}$? Omitting the $+c$ part

Comment: Nope. Your answer appears correct.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, $\lambda > 0$ must be assumed.

Another way: 
$$ \lambda x e^{-\lambda x} = - \lambda \dfrac{\partial}{\partial\lambda}  e^{-\lambda x}$$

$$ \eqalign{\int_0^R \lambda x e^{-\lambda x} \; dx &= 
- \lambda \dfrac{d}{d\lambda} \int_0^R e^{-\lambda x}\; dx = -\lambda \dfrac{d}{d\lambda} \left(\dfrac{1}{\lambda} - \dfrac{e^{-\lambda R}}{\lambda}\right) = \dfrac{1}{\lambda} + (\ldots) e^{-\lambda R}\cr
&\to \dfrac{1}{\lambda} \text{ as } R \to \infty\cr}
$$

And yet another, and more general:

The Maclaurin series for $g(s) = \int_0^\infty e^{(s-1) \lambda x}\; dx$  is
$$ g(s) = \int_0^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{s^n \lambda^n x^n}{n!} e^{-\lambda x}\; dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{s^n}{n!} \int_0^\infty \lambda^n x^n e^{-\lambda x}\; dx$$

But $$g(s) = \dfrac{1}{(1-s)\lambda} = \frac{1}{\lambda} \sum_{n=0}^\infty s^n$$
so for nonnegative integers $n$
$$\int_0^\infty \lambda^n x^n e^{-\lambda x}\; dx = \dfrac{n!}{\lambda}$$